# How to replace string after colon using sed, awk, regex, yq etc and can run using shell script

Tags: regex, awk, sed, yq

I have a yaml file and in that file I need to replace a specific string that comes after oauth2accesstoken: using a shell script

my current shell script :-

```
#!/bin/sh

password=$(gcloud auth print-access-token)

password="$password" yq -i '.stringData.creds |= "oauth2accesstoken:" + strenv(password)' /test.yaml
```

Lets Assume Replace Value is "**abcdefg1234**"

File :-

```
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: cred
type: Opaque
stringData:
  creds: oauth2accesstoken:ya29.a0AJ8fv7hrWsNVlDaXa-j6IUwBRdxt6GDDXMu1234efrtyhAjPWx0uw0174 # dummy key
```

Output Should be like this:-

```
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: cred
type: Opaque
stringData:
  creds: oauth2accesstoken:abcdefg1234
```

Error:-

```
Error: unknown command ".stringData.creds |= \"oauth2accesstoken:\" + strenv(password)" for "yq"
Run 'yq --help' for usage.
```

**Note:**-Above keys are dummy keys.

Comment: It is a YAML file, use YAML syntax aware tools like yq - https://stackoverflow.com/tags/yq/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Go yq aka [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/), its pretty straightforward to just select the right field and update its value

```
yq '.stringData.creds |= "oauth2accesstoken:abcdefg1234"' yaml
```

or pass the value from a shell variable

```
token="abcdefg1234" yq '.stringData.creds |= "oauth2accesstoken:" + strenv(token)' yaml
```

To modify the file in-place use the `-i` flag e.g. `yq -i <rest-of-the-code>`. Tested on version 4.27.5

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/(oauth2accesstoken:).*/\1:abcdefg1234/g' input.txt
```

This will search for line with oauth2accesstoken and replace all after it.

Comment: Can I able to change the value "abcdefg1234" to $password, means any variable?

Comment: @gauravagnihotri Yes, but you need to change to duble quote to use variable inside the sed.  Example: `sed -i "s/$var1/ZZ/g" "$file"`

Answer (score 0):

```
front=$(sed -n '/creds/p' file | cut -d':' -f1-2)
back="abcdefg1234"

echo "${front}:${back}" >> file

cat > ed1 <<EOF
$
-1d
wq
EOF

ed -s file < ed1
rm -v ./ed1
```